# Questions about Android Security are on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I see no common rule across Android questions on IS SE. For example [my post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220702/prevent-unsolicited-malicious-app-install-on-android) about possible infection of Android device was considered off-topic, however [this typical broad question post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/best-practices-for-securing-an-android-device) which gives generic recommendations is perfectly on-topic. What is the point?

In [don't ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) there is no single section that mentions Android and [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/do-we-need-a-canonical-question-on-infected-android-and-ios) also there was no consensus. Can anybody explain the policy?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your question was specific about the process for how to determine how this one app was installed.

Broad general questions of security on certain devices are on-topic here. But "how do I do X on system Y?" are better asked on the sites dedicated to that system (Server Fault for servers, Super User for general consumer devices, Ask Different for Mac, etc.)

Comment: Ok, but as it seems canonical question [as discussed here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/do-we-need-a-canonical-question-on-infected-android-and-ios) is needed anyway. There are not so much security pros on Android SE and here might be better audience

Comment: But you don't need a security pro for what you asked. Ultimately, what you asked was not a security question. It has security implication, but is not about security. You asked for the process/commands for a particular task.